# Which tessellations of convex polytopes can be expressed as power diagrams?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, convex-geometry

Someone once told me that all tessellations of convex polytopes in Euclidean space can be realized as the [power diagram](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_diagram) of some set of points (with appropriately associated radii). I do not think this is true, because power diagrams have the restrictive property that the line segment connecting two adjacent circle centers crosses their border between the cells at a right angle.

My question is about the converse of this fact: For a tessellation of convex polytopes in $\mathbb R^d$, if it is known that

- each polytope in the tessellation can be associated to a point such that
- the line segment between any points associated to adjacent polytopes intersects the shared boundary at a right angle,

then can the tessellation be realized as a power diagram of some set of points with appropriately associated radii?

Comment: What is a "power diagram"?